# how does iteration sort array?

Tags: java, loops, sorting, iteration

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] arr = new int[] { 300, 550, 137 };

        int temp;

        // traverse 0 to array length
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++)

            // traverse i+1 to array length
            for (int j = i + 1; j < arr.length; j++)

                // compare array element with
                // all next element
                if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {

                    temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }

        // print all element of array
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(arr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

The above code will output 137,300,550. 
Shouldn't it be 300,137,550?
How does it work after the last loop?

Comment: What do you mean by after the last loop? What you are seeing in the code, is bubble sort. https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/bubble-sort/

Comment: why is it not 300,137,550? How does it know that it should continue till its sorted instead of just looping till array length -1 @GauravJeswani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's sorting because you are using bubble sort. If you debug the loops you will understand clearly.
initially `i=0` and `j=1`

- step 1: `300>550 ? False` `i=0,j=2;`
- step 2: `300>137 ? true` inside if condition `temp =300;arr[0]=137;arr[2]=300;` `i=0;j=3;`
- step 3: inner loop will break. `i=1;` and value in `arr={137,550,300}`
- step 4: `i=1;j=2;` 550>300 ? true inside if condition `temp =550; arr[1]=300;arr[2]=550;` `i=1;j=3;`
- step 5: inner loop will break and value in `arr={137,300,550}`
- parent loop will break.

I hope, now it will be clear to you.